# HttpClient strikethrough

Tags: android, httpclient, strikethrough

when I try to create new HttpClient, it appears like this  ̶H̶t̶t̶p̶C̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶

Comment: its just to acknowledge you that HttpClient is deprecated . still you can use it , if you want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to create new HttpClient, it appears like this  H̶t̶t̶p̶C̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶

The method `HttpClient` is deprecated.

you can use [**`HttpURLConnection`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

**here is the simple demo code how to use `HttpURLConnection` with  `AsyncTask`**

```
        public static class GetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");


        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");// here you can set request method like GET and POST
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);// here you can set connection time out
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);// here you can set Read Time out
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }


        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

than use like this

```
GetAsyncTask getAsyncTask = new GetAsyncTask();
    try {
        String str=getAsyncTask.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what should I do then, replace it? with what?

Comment: it should be in comment

Comment: @HossameMakhlof check updated ans

Comment: @ND1010_ really dude

Comment: @Prem so should change the php method from GET to POST ??

Comment: @HossameMakhlof no you can use both GET and POST method as per your requirement check in my ans i have mention it

Comment: @Perm Thank you Boss !  :D

Comment: @HossameMakhlof happy to help you